# CSS Parallax Background

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am currently developing https://dev.shivampaw.com/me and I have a class called "parallax-bg" which should make a parallax background.

For my contact (section) right at the bottom, it isn't working yet for my hero (top) and texture (middle) it works fine.

This is the jQuery I am using:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.parallax-bg').css('background-position', 'center ' + ((scrolledY) - 70) + 'px');
});
```

And the CSS for the contact form section is just:

```
section#contact{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 0.65) 100%), url(https://www.shivampaw.com/images/bg-contact.jpg) no-repeat center -70px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    color: white;
}
```

And for the hero section:

```
section#hero{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 0.65) 100%), url(https://www.shivampaw.com/images/top-bg.jpg) no-repeat center -70px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Update: by parallax I mean fixed background. I use jquery so it works on mobiles as well.

Comment: I don't think it is working for texture as well. It just "looks" like it is but the texture image is not really moving. It is infact behaving the same as your hero image - image is **fixed** but the website is scrolling

Comment: Try changing/adding this to your sections `background-attachment: fixed;` not `scroll`

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa see my update

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing my jQuery to the following:

```
$(window).on('scroll resize load',function(){
    // 500px
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.parallax-bg').each(function(){
        $obj = $(this);
        var pixelsY = $obj.data("position");
        $obj.css('background-position', 'center ' + ((scrolledY) + pixelsY) + 'px');
    });
});
```

And add a data attribute called position in my html where the class parallax-bg is. This represented my desired background position y offset which fixed the problem.

I also removed the no-repeat from the CSS.